# How to delete AutoComplete string in dialogFieldValue in my Dialog?

Tags: caching, dialog, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I created a **Dialog** I have this code:

```
dialog     dialog;
DialogText dialogText ;
DialogButton dialogButton;
DialogField dialogFieldI, dialogFieldII;
str fieldDel, confirm;
MyTableDelete tabledelete;

dialog = new Dialog("Dialog name");
dialog.addText("Write to confirm");
dialog.addText("DELETE");

dialogFieldI = dialog.addFieldValue(extendedTypeStr(String30), fieldDel , "Insert value");
dialogFieldII = dialog.addFieldValue(extendedTypeStr(String30), confirm, "Confirm delete");

dialog.run();
confirm = dialogFieldIi.value();
fieldDel = dialogFieldI.value();

if(dialog.closedOk() )
{
    if(confirm == "DELETE")
    {
      ttsBegin;
      select forUpdate tableDelete
      where tableDelete.field == fieldDel;
      tableDelete.delete();
      ttsCommit;
    }
}
```

I have a problem, when I launch the firts time, in my **dialog.addFieldValue** 
there's nothing, but If I launch the **Dialog** second time, in **dialogField** automatically appears the suggestion of the text "DELETE".

Exist a method to clean (cacheclean) after the click.

My focus is not make it easy insertion Confimr text ("DELETE").

If it were possible to know also how to compare with the uppercase in the if() statements for me it would be a good thing.

I add a pictures , I want to delete the automatic composition sentence:

[image: my dialog]

Thanks your time,

enjoy!

Comment: If you are talking about the auto complete feature of AX, take a look at http://kashperuk.blogspot.de/2014/12/tutorial-auto-complete-functionality-on.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually more complicated than I initially thought, unless I'm missing an easier way.  I was able to reproduce your issue and the way I solved it was by using a method `delAutoCompleteString()` which exists on the `formRun()`, which is created when you call `dialog.run()` or it can be pre-created by calling `dialog.doInit()`.

This was fun to solve, so hopefully this helps someone else with the same issue.  This is disabling auto complete on a form control.

> // Added these three lines in code block below
>
> dialog.doInit();
>
> dialog.formRun().delAutoCompleteString(dialogFieldI.control());
>
> dialog.formRun().delAutoCompleteString(dialogFieldII.control());

Look at the adjusted code where I added these 3 lines.:

```
dialog     dialog;
DialogText dialogText ;
DialogButton dialogButton;
DialogField dialogFieldI, dialogFieldII;
str fieldDel, confirm;
MyTableDelete tabledelete;

dialog = new Dialog("Dialog name");
dialog.addText("Write to confirm");
dialog.addText("DELETE");

dialogFieldI = dialog.addFieldValue(extendedTypeStr(String30), fieldDel , "Insert value");
dialogFieldII = dialog.addFieldValue(extendedTypeStr(String30), confirm, "Confirm delete");

    
// AlexOnDAX (06/08/2015)
// Added these lines
//-->
dialog.doInit();
dialog.formRun().delAutoCompleteString(dialogFieldI.control());
dialog.formRun().delAutoCompleteString(dialogFieldII.control());
//<--
    
dialog.run();
confirm = dialogFieldIi.value();
fieldDel = dialogFieldI.value();

if(dialog.closedOk() )
{
    if(confirm == "DELETE")
    {
        ttsBegin;
        select forUpdate tableDelete
        where tableDelete.field == fieldDel;
        tableDelete.delete();
        ttsCommit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, you are very kind. Good code!!

Answer (score 2):

Your code as written won't work.  `Dialog` is not initialized and I don't see any way that it put "Delete" in the dialogField.  I'm guessing we are missing some code, but you need to disable loading from **SysLastValue**.

**EDIT Adding Jan's comment:** Consider using `addField` instead of `addFieldValue` and see if this is the cause.

If your code is run from a controller, you would do:

`controller.parmLoadFromSysLastValue(false);`

Comment: Using `addField` instead of `addFieldValue` might do the trick!

Comment: I quickly copied & pasted his code and changed it to work and wasn't able to duplicate his issue. Did that happen for you?

Comment: Hi all, when I copied my code I forgot to initialized the Dialog, I edited my answer's code. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexK thanks for your help, I don't understand how can use the method controller.parmLoadFromSysLastValue(false); for my dialog.addFieldValue . I found examples of use only to Report. Thanks, I appreciate your help

Comment: @ulisses, you need to post your full code. Your code example is missing too much for anyone to really help. You don't have `Dialog dialog = new Dialog()` in the code, so that at a very minimum shows we're not seeing the entire picture.

Comment: Thanks @AlexK for your reply. I edited my answer, I need to remove the 
automatic completion of the sentence with the previous one. Very thanks for your time!

Comment: @ulisses - See my other answer I added below.  I left this answer too because it is correct for other scenarios.